# ParameterMissing error : Update a record in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to update count:=count-1 for the product. I used edit instead of update is because I would like to skip the form. I also listed the route that generated by the system.

Here is the Error: "ActionController::ParameterMissing in ProductsController#edit"

Product_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  if @product.update(product_params)
    render json: { status: :ok, message: 'Product updated ', data: @product }
  else
    render json: { status: :error, message: 'Product not available', data: @product }
  end
end

private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price, :count)
  end
```

Edit.html.erb

```
      <%= form_with(model: @product, local: true) do |form| %>

      <% if @product.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
          <%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
    this product from being saved:
     </h2>
      <ul>
         <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
      </ul>
     </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
     <%= form.label :title %><br>
     <%= form.text_field :title %>
   </p>

  <p>
     <%= form.label :price %><br>
     <%= form.text_field :price %>
   </p>

   <p>
     <%= form.label :count %><br>
     <%= form.text_field :count %>
   </p>

   <p>
     <%= form.submit %>
 </p>

 <% end %>
```

Routes:

```
    welcome_index_path  GET /welcome/index(.:format)    welcome#index

    products_path   GET /products(.:format) products#index

    POST    /products(.:format) products#create

    new_product_path    GET /products/new(.:format) products#new

    edit_product_path   GET /products/:id/edit(.:format)    products#edit

    product_path    GET /products/:id(.:format) products#show

    PATCH   /products/:id(.:format) products#update

    PUT /products/:id(.:format) products#update

    DELETE  /products/:id(.:format)  products#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to update the record you can use update method

Product_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  # use update method
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  # you can count down here
  @product.count = @product.count - 1
  # use update_attributes to update the record
  if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
    render json: { status: :ok, message: 'Product updated ', data: @product }
  else
    render json: { status: :error, message: 'Product not available', data: @product }
  end
end

private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price, :count)
  end
```

Comment: I have one edit.html.erb, which displays the information of the record. How can I skip it, so that return the message directly?

Comment: I used your code, but have the error in the update statement:ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: product):

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:64:in `product_params'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:45:in `update'

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting "ActionController::ParameterMissing in ProductsController#edit" then that is a signal from strong_params that a required param is not in your parameters.

Your required param is :product so you would expect your params to have something like:
`product: {some_key: :some_value}`

Check your params in your edit action before the call to update with a puts statement or a binding.pry like `params.inspect`

(also side note if this is your action where you are updating the object then this action should be called "update", not "edit")

This sounds like an issue with your view - you probably have the form_for formatted incorrectly and thus the params are not formatted correctly coming into your controller. It would be best to include your view code in this question as well. For reference on how to format form_for check out https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html